# Validate SoundCloud URL via javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 2 urls from soundcloud that I would like to get everything after the .com/(or).sc/, I don't understand regex at all, I could do the javascript match/replace, only problem is the http vs https

```
https://soundcloud.com/ilyao/lyao-lj-mtx-and-lj-mtxs-hair

http://snd.sc/1cvgIjv
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's what I've got, not sure how to do the https of the replace or if this is the best way to approach this...

```
function getSoundCloudInfo(url){
    return url.replace("https://soundcloud.com/", "").replace("http://snd.sc/", "");
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: @HamZa I just added what I'm currently using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function getSoundCloudInfo(url){
  var regexp = /^https?:\/\/(soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)\/(.*)$/;
  return url.match(regexp) && url.match(regexp)[2]
}
```

Comment: The dot in `soundcloud.com` and `snd.sc` should be escaped, otherwise the validation will pass for domains like `soundcloudscom`. `/^https?:\/\/(soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)\/(.*)$/`

Comment: [snd.sc is no longer a thing.](https://soundcloudcommunity.com/share-embed-230064/custom-url-shortener-6976480)

Answer (score 6):

It is too late, but...

**Don't forget about:**

1. mobile version (`m.` after http(s)://)
2. possible slash at the end
3. with or without `SSL/TLS`, so it can be `http` or `https`
4. with or without `www`

So, full regex is:

`^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[\w\-\.]+(\/)+[\w\-\.]+/?$`

Answer (score 4):

```
((https:\/\/)|(http:\/\/)|(www.)|(m\.)|(\s))+(soundcloud.com\/)+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(\/)+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const FULL_YOUTUBE_REG_EXP = /^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?youtube\.com\/watch.*v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/
const SHORT_YOUTUBE_REG_EXP = /^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?youtu\.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/
const VIMEO_REG_EXP = /^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)/
const SOUNDCLOUD_REGEXP = /^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?(soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)\/(.*)$/
```

Comment: Since OP has signified that they don't fully know how to use regex, it might be useful to do some explaining / show these regex in context. Also not sure why you're displaying the youtube and vimeo regexs...